# Translate SOAP response into a CSV using Python

Tags: python, csv, xml

**I have this XML from a SOAP call:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <SessionID xmlns="http://www.gggg.com/oog">5555555</SessionID>
    <QueryResult xmlns="http://www.gggg.com/oog/Query" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Code>testsk</Code>
      <Records>
        <Record>
          <dim_id>1</dim_id>
          <resource_full_name>Administrator, Sir</resource_full_name>
          <resource_first_name>Sir</resource_first_name>
          <resource_last_name>Administrator</resource_last_name>
          <resource_email>username@mailserver.com</resource_email>
          <resource_user_name>admin</resource_user_name>
        </Record>
        <Record>
          <dim_id>2</dim_id>
          <resource_full_name>scheduler, scheduler</resource_full_name>
          <resource_first_name>scheduler</resource_first_name>
          <resource_last_name>scheduler</resource_last_name>
          <resource_email>username@mailserver.com</resource_email>
          <resource_user_name>scheduler</resource_user_name>
        </Record>
```

**My goal:**
To parse each Record's sub-elements <dim_id> ... <resource_user_name> and save each record as a row in a CSV.

**My Code:**

```
dim_id_list = []
full_name_list = []
first_name_list = []
last_name_list = []
resource_email_list = []
resource_user_name_list = []

root = et.parse('xml_stuff.xml').getroot()

for dim_id in root.iter('{http://www.gggg.com/oog/Query}dim_id'):
    dim_id_list.append(dim_id.text)

for resource_full_name in root.iter('{http://www.gggg.com/oog/Query}resource_full_name'):
    full_name_list.append(resource_full_name.text)

for resource_first_name in root.iter('{http://www.gggg.com/oog/Query}resource_first_name'):
    first_name_list.append(resource_first_name.text)

for resource_last_name in root.iter('{http://www.gggg.com/oog/Query}resource_last_name'):
    last_name_list.append(resource_last_name.text)

for resource_email in root.iter('{http://www.gggg.com/oog/Query}resource_email'):
    resource_email_list.append(resource_email.text)

for resource_user_name in root.iter('{http://www.gggg.com/oog/Query}resource_user_name'):
    resource_user_name_list.append(resource_user_name.text)

rows = zip(dim_id_list, full_name_list, first_name_list, last_name_list, resource_email_list, resource_user_name_list)

with open('test.csv', "w", encoding='utf16', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Is there a better way to loop through the Records? This code is terribly verbose. I tried this:

```
for record in root.findall('.//{http://www.gggg.com/oog/Query}Record'):
    dim_id = record.find('dim_id').text
# Extract each attribute, save to list. etc.
```

But I am getting attribute errors trying to access each record's text property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes little sense to slice the data into "vertical" lists, then transpose them back into rows using `zip()`.  Not only is it cumbersome to do it that way, it's also fragile.  If, for example, one records is missing its `resource_email` child element, then all subsequent rows will be off!

You can use `writer.writerows(rows)` instead of the `for row in rows: writer.write(row)` loop.  Furthermore, you can pass a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) so that the CSV writer extracts records on the fly as needed.

It's customary to `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` rather than as `et`.

### Suggested solution

```
import csv
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

fieldnames = [
    'dim_id',
    'resource_full_name',
    'resource_first_name',
    'resource_last_name',
    'resource_email',
    'resource_user_name',
]
ns = {'': 'http://www.gggg.com/oog/Query'}

xml_records = ET.parse('xml_stuff.xml').find('.//Records', ns)
with open('test2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf16', newline='') as f:
    csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames).writerows(
        {
            prop.tag.split('}', 1)[1]: prop.text
            for prop in xr
        }
        for xr in xml_records
    )
```

If you are certain that each `<Record>` always has its child elements in the right order, you can simplify it further by not explicitly stating the element/field names:

```
import csv
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

ns = {
    '': 'http://www.gggg.com/oog/Query',
    'soapenv': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
}

records = ET.parse('xml_stuff.xml').find('soapenv:Body/QueryResult/Records', ns)
with open('test2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf16', newline='') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(
        [prop.text for prop in r] for r in records
    )
```